# EV3 SPIK3R Mission 2 doesn't move

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, robotic

So I was building [Spik3r](http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/build-a-robot/spik3r) and I thought I got mission 2 completed. Wheels are turning, legs are moving but the robot just does not move.

It looks like the small wheels should be moving the robot but they barely touch the table surface.

https://youtu.be/2CFU0wDw-j4

Comment: It looks like the wheels aren't correctly mounted. As far as I remember you're right that the Spik3r is moving with the small wheels. Can you provide an image or two from the bottom of your model? It's hard to guess what happens just with the video on YouTube.

Comment: Thank you!  While taking a photo of the model I notized that the front engine is wrong way. http://imgur.com/PINYPDb

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer so that this question doesn't mistakeably be considered an unanswered question?

Comment: no, I need to someone answer that one.