# LEGO Mindstorms Spik3r won't move

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I built my Spik3r as usual, but it wouldn't run when I tried to program it. I checked the wheels and the legs and everything seemed fine. I even looked back in the instructions, and redid it. **It still wouldn't move**. The wheels and the spikes moved, but when I set it on the ground, it only wiggled around. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you embed some photos of that? We couldn't post an effective answer now because we don't know how you created Spik3r.

Comment: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8007/ev3-spik3r-mission-2-doesnt-move and https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/spik3r-wheels-move-but-the-spik3r-itself-doesnt are quite similar questions to this one.  Maybe comments from those could be useful.